# C# Console Output of webpage to JSON

Tags: c#, json, http

I am fetching webpage with the following code. (copied from an intelligent programmer. To learn and stop hating MSFT). Now I have two questions.

1. What is the format of output i.e. is it plain HTML or JSON
2. If its not JSON then how to convert the output to JSON and export to CSV.

   ```
   namespace getre
   {
       class Class1
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               string sURL;
               sURL = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_basic_syntax.htm";

               WebRequest wrGETURL;
               wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

               WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("myproxy", 80);
               myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;

               wrGETURL.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();

               Stream objStream;
               objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

               StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

               string sLine = "";
               int i = 0;

               while (sLine != null)
               {
                   i++;
                   sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
                   if (sLine != null)
                       Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, sLine);
               }
               Console.ReadLine();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Well the result will be what the page returns... if it returns JSON, it will be JSON, if it returns HTML it will be HTML and so on. Also, based on the structure of the data, it may not be that easy or nice to flatten it in a csv file...

Comment: @Bartdude Is there any way by which we can determine the result type in the program or change it to JSON if it's not.

Comment: well it can be pretty much anything from simple string to JSON formatted string or HTML or XML. Usually when you do a request on a given URL you know what you expect it to be. A possibility could be to try to parse it and hope the parser sends an error if the format isn't good. That way you can iterratively find what it could be. But if you don't even know if it's returning JSON, there's no way you can structure it in JSON if it's not...

Comment: You can do do some try catch nesting to attempt to serialize the json, if that fails perhaps HTML parsing and if that fails move on to XML. Is there only 1 page you are attempting to get or you trying to make it ambiguous and catch all? If its just 1 page open it in a browser and see what the format is and code accordingly.  Otherwise your stuck guessing minus the answer below and that's dependent on if the coder provided that information.  Your not just going to be able to transform 1 format into another. You would need to build a parser for each format.

Comment: @Bartdude Its HTML. Thanks to Adrian for giving the code. Since I have started learning C# 2 days ago hence very slow in learning. Now how can I convert the HTML to JSON if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the console app is a custom format made up of a line number and the line content (separated by a ':') for each line of the response content (excluded any `null` lines!?).

If you want to check the content type before processing, then you can insert the lines:

```
WebResponse response = wrGETURL.GetResponse();

string contentType = response.ContentType;
```

If you're lucky the server/programmer will have set this in the response on the target website and it might be "text/html" or "application/json".

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. Looking at the result. Its HTML so how can I convert these to JSON if possible.

Comment: @LonelySoul You can't really, JSON (like XML) is more about data structures, whereas HTML is a mark-up language.  Do you have control over the server that you are making the request to?  If it's one of your own applications then you could ask whoever develops the content to deliver the data in whatever format you like.

Comment: Oh see we have hit the Wall. Unfortunately no. And thanks for the knowledge in JSON and HTML, I was completely dumb at the first point.

Comment: On the plus side, if what you're attempting is to get a web page from another site and then try to extract the data from it, there's a whole bunch of people doing the same thing.  It's generally called *screen scraping*, a quick Google might give you some other options and tools you could try.  It's a popular topic on Stackoverflow too.

Comment: Thats a good lead. However my end goal is to deal with OAuth like fb,twitter etc. And saw some of the libs on the API's with C#. Not impressive and very limited in cpacity.